# Loading XML layout from web service

Tags: java, android

My question is more a curiosity:

Is there any way to load an external xml layout from web service.

E.g.
Download XML File > Load XML layout with setContentView ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. This is what can be found in [the LayoutInflater docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) :

> For performance reasons, view inflation relies heavily on
>   pre-processing of XML files that is done at build time. Therefore, it
>   is not currently possible to use LayoutInflater with an XmlPullParser
>   over a plain XML file at runtime; it only works with an XmlPullParser
>   returned from a compiled resource (R.something file.)